# document.getElementById('').scrollHeight doesn't get the actual height

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I have a div where it nest text, images that is changed more often and so the height of the div changes accordingly..

I need to get the height of div.

I have tried the jquery `$("div#ID").height();` but it always returns a value smaller than the actual height, any help please?

Comment: Smaller?  How much smaller?  Is it consistent?  Show more code.  CSS, HTML, etc.  What is the context?  How are you triggering that?

Comment: Please provide an example, maybe on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Is there any padding on the wrapper-element? Maybe try using `.outerHeight`

Comment: Thank you Sparky672 and GNi33 here is a jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/nWvA4/1/ I have also tried outerheight

Comment: There's no jQuery in your jsFiddle.  I thought this was a jQuery issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try,

```
$("#divID").outerHeight();
$("#divID").outerHeight(true); //includes margin of element
```